# Strict Json Enforcing when using @RequestBody

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, jackson

I've noticed when using @RequestBody MyObject that if you don't specify all the parameters in json that they are given default values anyway.

```
public class MyObject {

    @JsonCreator
    public MyObject (@JsonProperty("a") long a,
                     @JsonProperty("b") double b,
                     @JsonProperty("c") String c,

}
```

So a json request of the following:

```
{
 "a" : 0
}
```

Will produce the following once deserialized

```
c == null, b == 0.0, a = 0
```

The controller method, where the json is deserialized by requestbody is as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/doSomething/"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody void something(@RequestBody MyObject myObject) {
    //  Logic here. 
}
```

Is there someway I can enforce requestbody to ensure all the parameters are there when parsing the json into an object?

EDIT:

So a string for example will be given a null value while a double will be given a value of 0.0.

From what I've read this is expected from the jackson library that I am using. The goal is to know when the json being deserialized into an object whether there are missing json attributes instead of having them automatically given default values instead.

Comment: Please give an example of what you've _noticed_.

Comment: I've updated the question. I seem to have a problem on SO where most of my questions go unanswered so any constructive advice on naming/phrasing/explaining would be appreciated.

Comment: How would you like to know if there are missing members? Through an exception?

Comment: An exception would work. I just need to know when the json is not valid so that I can stop from continuing.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by implementing some validation on the objects with the @valid annotation. (javax.validation.Valid)

The controller now has  an @Valid annotation next to the requestbody and a bindingresult object which will allow me to check whether the bind was succesful or not.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/doSomething/"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody void something(@Valid @RequestBody MyObject myObject, BindingResult bindingResult) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return bindingResult.toString();
    }

}
```

My object now looks like the following:

```
public class MyObject {
    @NotNull private Long a;
    @NotNull private Double b;
    @NotNull private String c;

   // And so on... 

}
```

Switching the primitives types to objects instead meant that if these values were missing from json than they would be attempted to given null values which were not valid solving my issue.

More information here: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-31-valid-requestbody